# How i can return value after http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var content = 'now - not content';

const getHtmlCode = function(){
  request(url, function(req, resp, body){
    content = body;
  });
  return content;
};

console.log(getHtmlCode()); // >> now - not content
```

In console i can see **/now - not content/** because request to site takes 2-3 second.

**Bad solution:** i can add setTimeout on return, but this is very bad way.

*How i can wait before return content ?*

Comment: You need to either use promises or async/await. There are a ton of really good articles out there as well as several good replies on this site that should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case perform the `console.log()` operation in the callback, i.e.

```
var content = 'now - not content';

const getHtmlCode = function(){
    request(url, function(req, resp, body){
        console.log(body);
    });
};

getHtmlCode();
```

If you prefer to use a promise you could try the code below;

```
function getHtmlCode(){
    return new Promise ((resolve, reject)=>{
        request(url, function(req, resp, body){
            if(!body) reject({message: "No body"});
            resolve(message);
        });
    });
}

getHtmlCode().then((body)=>{
    console.log(body)
}).catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: Mark as correct if this answered your question